# Is it bad to run a fake initial migration during deployment? (Django)

Tags: django, deployment, django-migrations

When deploying my Django project, I kept getting this error:

```
W: psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "materials_location" already exists
W: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
--snip--
W: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "materials_location" already exists
```

While the problem seems self-explanatory, this error first started appearing after I manually altered the database when I had to rename apps and move models around apps. ("materials_location" was one of the things I'd added.)

I eventually found this solution: running `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` during the deploy hook (instead of just `python manage.py migrate`). This allowed Django...

> ...to skip an app’s initial migration if all database tables with the names of all models created by all CreateModel operations in that migration already exist.

Problem solved. The rest of the migration was applied correctly (which included the addition of fields to the existing models) and the project was deployed without any errors.

Is there a scenario where this solution could backfire down the line? Like, what if I deploy to a new server and make a brand new database? Or if I reset or squash migrations? I feel like this is safe, but straying from `python manage.py migrate` makes me uneasy.